# Why does nitrogen molecule have greater ionization energy than nitrogen atom?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, ionization-energy

I am studying an article in my book that $\ce{N2}$ molecule has higher ionisation than $\ce{N}$ atom and I have no clue it may be because of strong triply bonded atom then why this is not applicable to $\ce{F2}$, $\ce{F}$ and $\ce{O2}$, $\ce{O}$. Also explain and with reason for $\ce{N2}.$

Comment: I think you have a good point here, this is unusual.

Comment: And here's answer http://www.vias.org/genchem/chembonding_14777_04.html